# CKEditor - Upload URL is not called by plugin uploadimage

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I tried to search, but no luck for now. I integrated CKEditor 4.5.10 with uploadimage plugin (using Builder). I set the filebrowserUploadUrl and filebrowserBrowseUrl options when using CKEDITOR.replace.

No error (except the one stating I can't use local images that should be fixed when to image is uploaded and changed by the plugin).

I put a breakpoint as my first line in my upload PHP file, but I never get there. Yes, my debuging stuff is working perfectly as I can break using the Uploading tab in the image dialog.

I'm trying to copy/paste from Word an image with text using CTRL-C + CTRL-V.

What could I've missed ?

Code of initialization (I justed forked the imageuploader plugin to ameliorate it, so I have control over it) :

```
    var superAdminPlugins = 'sourcearea,elementspath,forms';
    var autoUploadPlugins = ''; //',uploadimage,uploadwidget'; // I already put them in VIA Builder
    var toRemovePlugin = ',resize';
    var toTestPlugin = ',base64image,ckeditortablecellsselection,autoembed,bgimage,backgrounds,pbckcode,tabletoolstoolbar';
    alert(CKEDITOR.getUrl('') + 'plugins/imageuploader/imgupload.php');
    ckEditor = CKEDITOR.replace(textareaId, {
        language: wee.currentLanguage,
        extraPlugins: 'allmedias,imageuploader' + autoUploadPlugins,
        removePlugins: superAdminPlugins + toTestPlugin + toRemovePlugin,
        toolbarCanCollapse: true,
        scayt_sLang: scaytLanguageToUse,
        youtube_width: 300,
        youtube_height: 300,
        filebrowserUploadUrl: CKEDITOR.getUrl('') + 'plugins/imageuploader/imgupload.php',
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: CKEDITOR.getUrl('') + 'plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php'
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share code ?what you done still now

Comment: Well, for now I have to go to bed, but I'll had the init code. Though, I think I already stated the essential.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki I just edited the question.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki I just discover that pasting a image from Paint is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered why it doesn't work. And indeed, it's normal, well kind of.

Copying an image from a picture editor creates an image using base64 encoding. So the image is included directly in the content thus accessible by the plugin.

Weirdly, copying only the image from MS Word does exactly the same thing, so it works! Yeah! But unfortunately, copying an image with text, the image is included as a link to a local file in a temporary folder. So, the content not being contained in the clipboard, the plugin can't use it.

I'll then try to create a Java software that will catch a clipboard change and adjust its content with base64 images instead. Hope I'll be able to do so! If yes, I'll post it somewhere.

**EDIT :**

Here is the Java software I made to support this :
https://github.com/djon2003/ClipboardImageToBase64